# Linux start without mount to /var

Tags: linux, rhel, filesystems, xfs

after reboot the rhel machine , we noticed that server isn't up

and when access the OS to single user mode we can see that `/var` not mounted

therefore we perform `xfs_repair` but its hang for `5 hours`

any suggestion how to continue ?

```
xfs_repair /dev/mapper/vg-mng-lv_var
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The disk that contains the filesystem/LV might be unavailable or failing.

I hope you have a reasonably up-to-date backup of this server.

Use `lvdisplay -m /dev/mapper/vg-mng-lv_var` (in single user mode it might be `lvm lvdisplay -m /dev/mapper/vg-mng-lv_var` instead) to identify the PV(s) the LV is located on.

If it's a simple local disk, check its health status with `smartctl -a /dev/<some_disk>`. If it's a hardware RAID set, use the diagnostic tools appropriate to that hardware RAID controller model to see if the disk(s) have failed.

If it's a remote iSCSI or FibreChannel SAN storage LUN, check that the system has a good connection to the SAN device: in case of fiberoptic connections, verify the cables are not kinked or otherwise damaged.

Replace broken things if necessary, then restore from backup.

If you don't have a backup, and the data on the disk is important, **stop right there**. Decide if the data on the disk is worth using professional data recovery services, or not.

If you plan to get the disk to a data recovery specialist, **do not do anything else with the disk:** you might damage it further, and cause the recovery to become more difficult or impossible.

Comment: I/O errors would appear in the `dmesg` output.